# Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса

Tags: c#

Словил ошибку на строке Session[guid + "data"] = dbCXD.getSqlTable(query,null);

conversion error from string "А" Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.

Сведения об исключении: FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: conversion error from string "А"

Ошибка источника:

```
{ //строка 66
    if (Request.QueryString["guid"] != null) //строка 67
        guid = Request.QueryString["guid"].ToString(); //строка 68
    else guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); }  //строка 69
 .....
query = query.Replace("#PERIOD#", cb_period.Value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')); //строка 369

Session[guid + "data"] = dbCXD.getSqlTable(query,null); //строка 370

} //строка 371
```

Исходный файл: c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\Controls\CM\constructor.ascx.cs Строка: 371

Трассировка стека:

> [IscException: conversion error from string "А"]*
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ProcessResponse(IResponse
> response) +70
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
> +60 FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version12.GdsStatement.Execute() +240 FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
> behavior, Boolean returnsSet) +293
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) +49
>
> [FbException (0x1400000e): conversion error from string "А"]
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior) +205 System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
> dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
> String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +214
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
> startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
> CommandBehavior behavior) +180
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
> srcTable) +123 YaKIT.C1.DataBase.FireBird.getSqlTable(String query)
> +447 YaKIT.C1.DataBase.DBConnect.getSqlTable(String query, List`1 lstParams) +499
>
> [Exception: YaKIT.C1.Database => getSqlTable :: select t1.*, t2.ORD as
> ULUS_CUSTOM_ORD from (select distinct f.nomer,f.namemest,f.okpo,
> f.oktmo,f.ulus, f.st, f.gr, f.zn from frm_data2019_0 f,
> s_okpo2019_period12 o, frm_form2019 t where f.okpo=o.okpo and
> t.kod=f.st and t.gr_st=2) t1 inner join S_ULUS t2 on t1.ULUS = t2.ULUS
>
> conversion error from string "А"]
> YaKIT.C1.DataBase.DBConnect.catchThrow(String message, Exception ex)
> +206 YaKIT.C1.DataBase.DBConnect.getSqlTable(String query, List`1 lstParams) +1031 CM_constructor.setSprData() in
> c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\Controls\CM\constructor.ascx.cs:371
> CM_constructor.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> c:\inetpub\YaKITv4.1.MSH\Controls\CM\constructor.ascx.cs:87
> System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +108
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +90
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +185
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1607*

Comment: пробовали запустить на прямую ваш скрипт select t1.*, t2.ORD as ULUS_CUSTOM_ORD from (select distinct f.nomer,f.namemest,f.okpo, f.oktmo,f.ulus, f.st, f.gr, f.zn from frm_data2019_0 f, s_okpo2019_period12 o, frm_form2019 t where f.okpo=o.okpo and t.kod=f.st and t.gr_st=2) t1 inner join S_ULUS t2 on t1.ULUS = t2.ULUS

Comment: @AzizUmarov в данное время не могу найти этот запрос в каком файле лежит, а так нет не пробовал